# ReactJS Axios отправляет больше одного запроса

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

Я чего-то не понимаю... Почему уходит 2 запроса? И как следствие приходит 2 ответа. Что не так?

Вот мой код

```
import {TodoItem} from "./TodoItem";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export function TodoList() {
    const [allTodo, setAllTodo] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo/`)
            .then(response => {
                response.data.forEach((todo) => {
                    setAllTodo(allTodo => [...allTodo, todo]);
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="TodoList">
            {
                allTodo.map((todo, index) => {
                    return <TodoItem key={index} data={todo}/>
                }
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect выполняется после каждого рендера.

- первый рендер происходит с пустым списком `[]`
- выполняется хук useEffect
- происходит первый запрос
- при получении данных выполняется хук setAllTodo
- данные изменились, поэтому происходит второй рендер
- выполняется хук useEffect
- происходит второй запрос

Comment: Так у useEffect пустой массив зависимостей. Второго срабатывания useEffect быть не может

Comment: setAllTodo меняет состояние полученным массивом. это вызывает рендер и useEffect https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html _useEffect представляет собой совокупность методов componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, и componentWillUnmount_ ... _Используя этот хук, вы говорите React сделать что-то после рендера. React запомнит функцию (то есть «эффект»), которую вы передали и вызовет её после того, как внесёт все изменения в DOM__

Comment: выведите в консоль allTodo в началк функции в useEffect. Должно вывестись сначала пустой массив, потом массив тудушек

Comment: Если список зависимостей пуст, второго вызова useEffect быть не может

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Спасибо за развернутый ответ!